# Load a form from the database

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a web site. In it, the person who maintains the site should have the possibility to create dynamic forms and save them in the database. Later the other users should be able to access those forms and enter data using those forms created by the maintenance staff.

My question is, the form is dynamically created in a PHP file using echo tags by the staff. What will be the easiest way to load those forms back when the other users are accessing it. Do I need to fetch the elements one by one from the database and display them to the user or are there any other possible ways available to load them back?

Comment: Not necessarily you need to create a form using `php echo`. Learn and the Use `Ajax` to load and show form.... Ajax is designed for this very application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way i can imagine to do this is to **serialize** the form fields and store them in one field in the db. When getting the form from the db, use the **unserialize** function and parse through every element. In this way, you have no limit on the number of fields and types.

Check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

The drawback of this method is that you won't be able to access one field of the form independently. You have to get the whole form and unserialize it first.

One other way is to use two tables:

1. Forms table which holds the basic information of the form (like form_id, action, method)
2. Form_fields table which holds the fields of each form. They are linked by the form_id index.

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: well serialize can only be used to handle data using GET method, in which there are some security issues. serializeArray is best method.

Comment: Process the $_GET data first. I didn't suggest serializing it directly. And by the way @UdayHiwarale, i'm talking about the PHP part.

Comment: Hi Dănuț Mihai Florian, thanks for replying. I have never used serielize() before. Does it store my form fieilds as a string? Can I access nd make active my fields in a bulky way without fetching them one by one?

Comment: Yes it stores all the forms as a string. I used this in a project and it looks like this:

Comment: a:6:{s:9:"form_type";s:3:"url";s:11:"form_action";s:58:"http://www.123contactform.com/my-contact-form--681743.html";s:10:"field_name";a:6:{i:1;s:14:"control5216481";i:0;s:14:"control5216482";i:2;s:14:"control5275675";i:3;s:14:"control5216483";i:4;s:14:"control5216483";i:5;s:14:"control5216483";}s:10:"field_type";a:6:{i:1;s:4:"text";i:0;s:4:"text";i:2;s:4:"text";i:3;s:8:"checkbox";i:4;s:8:"checkbox";i:5;s:8:"checkbox";}s:17:"field_placeholder";a:6:{i:1;s:15:...

Comment: It's a bulky way by default. When you access them you need to unserialize them into an array. Take a look at the php documentation that i posted above

Comment: great.. Danut could you please show me a small dummy answer with a question how you can do it. And one of my college told me that at the end of the form you can have a textarea and put the form data in to that using .innerHTML and send it to a field as a string into the database. Is it too possible? please create a small form and show me how you can serialize it. It will be a big help.

Comment: Read this: http://pastebin.com/EBugmGTC . I hope you understand what i wrote there...I'm a little bit tired :P

Comment: hehe :D No worries.. Yes that is really understandable. I will try it.. Thank u very much for giving a clue. Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Danut I found a problem. That is, I may not get css details, I had included to the from when Im retrieving the data from the database ryt?

Comment: No..you get only the values that you submit with the form